# Find all polynomials $p(x)$ satisfying condition

Tags: polynomials, periodic-functions

Find all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $\sin{p(x)}$ is periodic.

I think that the condition for the solution is $\deg{p(x)}\le 1$, but i can't find a formal way to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to meet

$$p(x+T)=p(x)+2k\pi$$ or

$$p(x+T)-p(x)=2k\pi.$$

But for the LHS to be continuous, $k$ must be constant, hence $p(x)$ must indeed be linear.

Comment: @Hasek: not at all. At this stage we don't know yet that the LHS must be constant, but we know it must be continuous as it is a polynomial.